# Apache2 doesn't start. Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, apache2, services

I've installed apache2, everything was fine. But after restart the system it doesn't start. When I open localhost in browser I get the error: ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED. I tried to start it by

```
sudo service apache2 start
```

The system doesn't give me any error, but also doesn't work.
The same things with

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 start
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: step 1: check if apache is running: `sudo service apache2 status`. step2: look into `var/log/apache2/error.log`.

Comment: sudo service apache2 status doesn't respond. It doesn't give any result